Aggressor nets are need to dump
how to dump all the aggressor nets for the victim nets by using tcl in PT Tool
report_delay_calculation -from <output pin> -to <input pin>

This will give aggressor nets for only one net ,But I need a Tcl script to dump Aggressor nets for all victim nets

Do you have lists of the aggressors and victims? Things that you could maybe iterate over with foreach?

you need to have a list of output and input pins and iterate over those two lists in a loop or you need to have a two regexp that gives all output pins and all input pins. and give this as inputs for the above cmd/proc
